# how to execute from a byte array without creating a physical file

Tags: go, memory

I packaged an exe using go-bindata. So I have a final executable after the build and another one which I can fetch back as asset as a byte array.

I dont want to create a file on the physical disk and execute the underlying executable. 
I want to protect this underlying exe from getting copied.

How else can I manage to execute the byte array. I am using Windows 10.

Regards,
DD

Comment: "I want to protect this underlying exe from getting copied." --- and now you have placebo protection, one still can copy the complete binary contents.

Comment: Ya I understand I am just trying to make it difficult to get to the underlying exe for a newbee. The wrapper will authenticate the user before letting him run the exe. He will need to extract the underlying exe binary to make it work. Thanks, do let me know if I am on a complete wrong track.

Comment: This is likely not possible in a reliable way on modern operating systems due to the security implications.

Comment: Just write it to a temporary directory with appropriate permissions and run it from there. You can do this after authentication and even delete the binary once it's running.